# Error while passing the parameters in junit

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, parameters, junit4

I am getting the error while passing the parameters in junit, can anyone suggest me the right format to pass the parameters. thanks in advance

```
Feature Elevation Messaging Service Test
Service Test
C Campaign Messaging Service.java
5
Git: 0 FileReadUtils.java >
Messaging Service.javax FeatureElevation Messaging Service Testjava x CampaignMessaging Service Test.java
@InjectMocks FeatureElevationMessagingService notificationMessage Processor;
Not
A4
@Mock Sender sender;
@Test @Parameters({ "{\"featureElevation\": {\"files\": [{\"name\": "policy.cab\", \"epochTime\": 12324324}, {\"name\": \"driver.cab\"," +
\"epochTime\": 12324327}],\"hubName\": \"DEV-APAC1\", \"filepath\": \"csv_file/filePath.csv\"}",
})
public void invalidEventData_processNotificationMessage_throwsException_for_featureElevation(String eventBody, String expectedException)
EventData eventData = new EventData(eventBody); Throwable thrown = cotchThrowoble(() -> notificationMessage Processor.processEventMessage (eventData)); Assertions.assertThat(thrown) withFailMessage( newErrorMessage: "InvalidDataException is not thrown")
.isNotNullO) .is Instanceof(InvalidDataException.class) .hasToString(expectedException);
@Test @Parameters
"{\"campaign\": {\"filepath\", \"filepath.csv\"
,\"id\": "testCampaign1\"\\,\"expiryDateTime": 1640772505000\\,\"hubName\":\"/
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Hey Hi, Thank u for ur response,I am new to stack overflow, where can I add image here, thanks in advance

Comment: You have a small bar on top of the text input box, there you can format text as code, insert images and more. You can't do that in comments so edit your original question.

Comment: I have edited it